# Using Regex Pattern and Matcher to print out number once only

Tags: java, regex

This piece of code is part of my programme and I am trying to print out the last integer value of the string only whenever the operator and the equals sign are together (e.g. ^=, *=, etc.).

Hence, if I enter `4 4 ^ 4 ^ 4 ^=`, I would only want to print out "4". The same counts if the number 4 is directly before the "^=", e.g. 4 4 ^ 4 ^ **4^=.**

My code is this:

```
if ((input.endsWith("^=")) | (input.endsWith("*=")) |
    (input.endsWith("+=")) | (input.endsWith("-=")) |
    (input.endsWith("%=")) | (input.endsWith("/=")))
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\d]*[\\d]+[^\\d]+([\\d]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); // second matched digits
    }
}
```

Currently my code prints out the number 4 multiple times, but I would only want to print it once. Any help is is appreciate.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean like `([0-9]+)\h*[\^+*]=(?!.*[\^+*]=)` https://regex101.com/r/OHlC6d/1

Comment: Kind of. Its also important that the calculation 4 2 ^ = prints out 16, whilst 4 2 ^= or 4 2^= prints out 2. Its only whenever the operator and equals sign are in directly following indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use:

```
([0-9]+)\h*[\^+%/*-]=(?!.*[\^+%/*-]=)
```

- `([0-9]+)` Capture 1+ digits 0-9 in group 1
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `[\^+%/*-]=` Match any of the listed followed by =
- `(?!.*[\^+%/*-]=)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right does not contain an operator followed by an equals sign

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sKGoRp/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/hW2Zny)

In Java

```
final String regex = "([0-9]+)\\h*[\\^+%/*-]=(?!.*[\\^+%/*-]=)";
```

Comment: thanks a lot! how can I adjust it so that it ONLY prints the number if the operator and equals sign are in following indexes? e.g. ^= is different to ^ =

Comment: @nurders04 You could use capturing groups and match the whitespaces in between, then use the group numbers in the replacement. https://ideone.com/pAhhAh Not sure what you mean by `if the operator and equals sign are in following indexes?`

Comment: great that helps a lot. for example., if I write ^= instead of ^ =. Id only want this to apply to the case where I write ^=, and keep the programme the same if that's not the case :)

Comment: The current pattern from the answer only matches when there is not whitespace between the operator and the equals sign https://regex101.com/r/vkbLMM/1

Comment: Yes that's true. The only problem I have is that it prints out the entire string, whilst it should only print out the last digit (in this case it is 4). I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You could match all and use only the first group in the replacement https://ideone.com/SkAJWn or in that case use `^.*([0-9]+)\h*[\^+%/*-]=.*$` https://regex101.com/r/krrhz2/1 which is almost the same pattern as in the other answer.

Comment: okay great. what would you advise would be best if we take an input from the command line? so we wouldn't define the string, but the user would. e.g. it could be any string of characters that the user inserts, but it would always just return the last digit once "+=", "-=", "/=", "%=", "*=" and "^=" is typed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(\d+)\s*[-+*/^%]=$
```

- Find 1 or more digits and capture them
- if they're followed by 0 or more spaces
- followed by -, +, *, /, ^ or %
- followed by =
- followed by the end of the string

Comment: thank you! how can I make the programme still do the calculations? e.g. 4 4 ^ = is different to 4 4 ^= (notice the difference where operator and = sign are together).